# Duplicate rows in Postgresql query result

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm a newbie in PostgreSQL and exercising some queries.

I want to find ' The person who was/were vaccinated after 2021-06-16 in the cities whose name starts with "G" or "V".

DB Tables:

Person Table

[image: Person Table]

Vaccination Table

[image: Vaccination Table]

My query:

```
select 
"Person".name,date,vaccination_info  from  public."Person", public."Vaccination" where date > '2021-06-16' and vaccination_info = true and ("Person".name like 'G%' or "Person".name like 'V%');
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Why I get duplicate rows in my query result and how can I eliminate these duplicates?

Comment: Is this real data that you are displaying in the question, or dummy data?

Comment: It is dummy data.

Comment: Well, obviously some persons have had more than one vaccination.

Comment: I would guess that the problem is that you are not correctly joining `Person` with `Vaccination`.  I see the syntax you are using uses older style joins - but that there doesn't seem to be any matching between the `Person` and `Vaccination` tables

Comment: @wildplasser All vaccination table is shown here. All persons are different in the vaccination table. There is a different logical problem in the query I guess.

Comment: Also, the column references dont have table-qualifiers. And `date` is a bad name for a column. And you have aa Carthesian product, thanks to the old-style join. And you appear to have two accounts on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

> The person who was/were vaccinated after 2021-06-16 in the cities whose name starts with "G" or "V".

That suggests that you want a query like this:

```
select p.name, v.date, p.vaccination_info 
from  public."Person" p join
      public."Vaccination" v
      on v.person_id = p.id
where v.date > '2021-06-16' and
      v.vaccination_info = true and
      (p.city like 'G%' or p.city like 'V%');
```

In addition to the proper `JOIN` syntax and conditions, note the use of table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.